# LabVIEW: create a named cluster as source for a ComboBox, containing a .NET object in 'Value'

Tags: .net, combobox, labview

I come from .NET and am trying to get into LabVIEW ...

The thing I fail is to build a named cluster in LabVIEW. The first element should be called 'String' and contain a id string identifying a .NET object. The second element should be called 'Value' and contain the .NET object.
The goal is to fill the property 'StringsAndValues' of a ComboBox with this named cluster for to be able to access the .net object after having clicked its corresponding string in the ComboBox.

Its possible to build a cluster of a string and a .NET object by using the function 'Bundle'. But is there a way to change the automatically created names?

I could not create a empty cluster on the front panel with named elements one of the having my specific .NET object type.

Any help appreciated.

Update, this is actually my best approach:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LabVIEW world it is a bit different than in .NET. Combobox contains strings only. It can not contain other objects.

Also, named clusters are useless in LabVIEW. Instead, you need to create cluster which will have fields: Name, and Object. Then you create array of such clusters - each element has name, and object which you store there (in your case some .NET object).

And then, using Combobox string value, you need to iterate through array of those above mentioned clusters, compare Combobox value with Name field, and when it is equal - get your object.

But there is also another way. You could use Variant Attribute, and build so-called lookup-table (which is hash table, actually). In newer LabVIEW versions (I guess starting from LabVIEW 2019) you could also use Maps or Sets for this.

I showed two approaches on the screenshot, hope they are clear.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me understand how to create an array of clusters with individual names ('String' and 'Value'), but when I try to feed the Property 'StringsAndValues[]' of a Combo Box, I get a type mismatch error ?

Comment: Source : 1D array of cluster of 2 elements  Sink : 'LVComboBoxStrsAndValuesArrayTypeDef.ctl' 1D array of cluster of 2 elements

Comment: Mismatch error is because Combobox "StringAndValues" property has "Value" as string data type. It is intended not for storing of objects. It is better practice to separate your backend data (.NET objects in your case) and UI (combobox selector). Today you use combobox for selection, and tomorrow could use Enum. So do not try to keep data in combobox, but instead use combobox just as selector.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use the Combobox now to just select the ids to
get the objects from am array of clusters of id and object.